# window.print() not working in iOS 9.2.1 when page is saved to home screen

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, ios9

I have a web app I've been using for a while without problems.  With Apple's update to iOS 9.2.1, window.print() no longer works when the page runs as a web app saved to the home screen.  If I run the page directly within safari, it works just fine.  When I save it to the home screen then click the print button, the app hangs on the print dialog then will crash after a minute or so.  Print preview also no longer works.  At this point, I'm assuming it is a bug in iOS 9.2.1 but wanted to post my code here in case someone sees a problem or can offer a suggestion.

Here's the test HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=0.6667, user-scalable=no" /> -->
<meta name="version" content="Version 3.0 Beta 3" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="YES" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="ADDRESS">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
</head>
<body>
<p>test page</p>
<form >
<input type="submit" value="Print" onClick="window.print();">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the cache file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

#version 3.1 Beta 3 7-20-2015

CACHE:


#internal HTML documents
index.html

NETWORK:
*
```